# How would I write LINQ to SQL to select rows where an ID is in an array of integers of unknown size?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Say I want to pass an array of integers into a method that runs some LINQ to SQL, how would I say something like "where SuchID is in array[] select"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Contains`.

```
int[] ids = // populate ids
var query = from e in db.SomeTable
            where ids.Contains(e.SuchID)
            select e;
```

LINQ to SQL will translate this to a `WHERE` clause using `IN`.